# How long should people wait before posting newly released movie spoiler questions

Tags: discussion, scope

Is there a perscribed courtesy period before posting questions on newly released movies? I've seen a couple "morning after" questions about previous nights newly released movies and thought to myself "Don't know. Haven't had a chance to see it yet." How soon is too soon when it comes to new movie questions?

Answer (score 11):

There is no waiting period.

From the [**FAQ**](https://movies.stackexchange.com/faq):

> Spoilers
>
> Please note that spoilers are allowed here and may be out in the open. Read at your own risk.
>
> The use of spoiler markup should be kept to a minimum, or not used at all if it is clear what Movie or TV Show is being discussed in the question. Use common sense and apply spoiler markup to cover only aspects of your post that you would think might be unexpected, such as references to other movies.
>
> Spoiler tags will be deleted from questions as nearly every question reveals details about a movie or TV show.

It is plain as day that our policy is *anything is fair game*.  We expect our users to use enough common sense to not read questions pertaining to titles they wish not be spoiled.

Comment: As long as things are plainly written (as clear as day), I will continue to use common sense to try to unread things I glance at the morning after the movie premieres.

Comment: @MajorStackings - a major spoiler in a title of a question should be reworded for a recent movie, so that you (and I) can avoid questions we don't wish to read yet.

Answer (score 1):

> How soon is too soon

There is another aspect to this. Questions get most attention in the first few days, maybe weeks, after asking and then quickly sink into oblivion. So if you really want to ask a question about a movie that you just saw as one of the first people on earth, you know that there will only a small audience that knows what you're talking about. As the audience grows, your question gets less and less hits.

So it is not just a matter of courtesy. It is *smart* to wait a few weeks. I think somewhere in time there is a **sweet spot** for asking a question. Not too soon, not too late.

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with Spoiler? I usually read all the spoiler first before deciding whether a movie is worth watching or not.

Comment: That's just a matter of taste. Many people hate spoilers, as they want to be impacted by the movie's twists and surprises. Just think of The Life of David Gale.